# Вывод конкретной строки из файла TXT

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

В файле 'data.txt' (пример):

```
/print - function
/def - function
/class - class
```

Необходимо запросить у пользователя название конкретной функции, а после вывести всю строку на экран. Не понимаю как правильно и легко сделать обработчик, чтобы он понимал: функция "/print" занимает нулевую строку (по индексу), а "/def" - первую и так далее... Это справочник, по типу встроенного - help(x).

Предполагаемое решение: перебирать условиями...

```
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
fd = f.readlines()
user_answer = input('Введите назв. функции: ').lower()
isanswer = '/' + user_answer

if isanswer == '/print':
    print(fd[0])
elif isanswer == '/def':
    print(fd[1])
elif isanswer == '/class':
    print(fd[2])
else:
    print('Не найдено')
```

Код выше является рабочим, но это не осуществляет конкретного поиска по файлу, а исключения создавать самому - это как-то не серьёзно. Ломаю мозги и почему-то уверен, что есть метод поиска и отображения куда проще, чем то что вы видите. Подскажите, как реализовать задуманное? :(

Comment: Обязательно формат файла именно такой? Нельзя ли использовать json?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов всё верно, немного почитав и понял, что с json будет гораздо проще, хотя думал будет наоборот. Не хотел углубляться и тратить время, а применение функций часто забываю. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы обработал файл и добавил его в словарь, где ключом будет название команды (типа `/print`), а значением вся строка файла

Пример:

```
name_by_command = dict()

with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        name = line.split()[0]
        name_by_command[name] = line

user_answer = input('Введите назв. функции: ').lower()
isanswer = '/' + user_answer

if isanswer in name_by_command:
    print(name_by_command[isanswer])
else:
    print('Не найдено')
```

Если без обработки, но с списком строк, тогда:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

user_answer = input('Введите назв. функции: ').lower()
isanswer = '/' + user_answer

command = None
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(isanswer):
        command = line
        break

if command:
    print(command)
else:
    print('Не найдено')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это решило мою проблему! <3

Comment: @PavelGod, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 0):

А я бы сделал вместо условий один цикл:

```
for x in fd:
    if x.find(isanswer) != -1:
        print(x)
    else:
        print('error')
```